# Фильтр для выбора файлов в android

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь выбрать только определенные типы файлов. Поиском пользовался и нашел варианты,сделал аналогично:

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        } else {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        }
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

       // intent.setType("*/*");


       intent.setType("file/*|application/pdf|application/docx|application/doc|application/zip|application/xlsx|application/rtf|application/txt|application/rar|application/rtf");

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException exp) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Файл не найден", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

но при запуске на устройствах api19+ доступ к файлам запрещен.Т.е смотрите скрин,я не моуг выбрать файлы для которых сделал фильтр 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что нужно, но можно для начала пройтись по директории, проверить расширения, если подходит то собрать из подходящих файлов массив, а дальше в цикле слать интенты для каждого файла, потому что скопом их открыть врядли получится  + из кода непонятно что конкретно интент должен открывать. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html это пригодится в комлекте с Intent.setClipData и флагами FLAG_GRANT_READ(WRITE)_URI_PERMISSION , да и объект URI реализует Parcelable.

Comment: @ A-Z
я же указал,что при указании фильтра для конкретных файлов с расширением эти файлы недоступны

Answer (score 2):

Не изобретайте велосипед и используйте почти стандартную библиотеку [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) - там это все давным давно разжевано и решено.